# Why Android SDK string No and Cancel same in resource?

Tags: android, android-resources

Interesting bug I found while regression test of android app.
android.R.string.no is the same as android.R.string.cancel, but, exact No is android.R.string.gpsVerifNo. Why so?

[image]

UPD: android.R.string.gpsVerifNo not public or not exist in all sdk versions

Comment: Backwards compatibility, most likely.